# Parsing Markdown in fancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancyBox in a web application I am developing and have run into a problem I think would make a good feature in fancyBox.

I am loading a .txt file (my changelog) in a fancyBox popup and would like it to parse as markdown.

My link looks like this...

```
<a class="changelog fancybox.ajax" href="changelog.txt">ChangeLog</a>
```

and the corresponding jQuery...

```
$(".changelog").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
```

It loads the file with no problems but it has no formatting at all, not even line breaks. I realise this is because the plugin is treating it as HTML but the content of the file *is* formatted with Markdown so I'd like it to display using this and not have to convert the contents of the file itself to HTML formatting.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might solve this, if I can get it working I'll branch fancyBox and suggest it as a feature.

Comment: You'll most likely have to be populating and creating this HTML within another div, and that is the one that you'll actually be opening with fancybox

Comment: Yeah I'm currently working on that solution, just wondered if it was something people had come across before and knew a solution for, it seems like to would be a useful feature for fancyBox to parse Markdown, no?

Comment: Potentially but it seems it would be easy enough to grab the file with ajax, put it as `.html()` of another div. You could add those abilities in the plugin if you expect to be doing it a lot!

Comment: As it happens the complete non formatting can be solved by using iframe as data type instead of an AJAX load, no markdown parsing but at least the line breaks are there.

Comment: can you post a sample of your .txt document (do you have html tags in it?)

Comment: @JFK There is no HTML in the .txt file